# Porting Yii1's $user->setState('key', 'value') to Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

I'm upgrading a Yii1 app to Yii2 and got stuck at porting

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('key', 'value');
Yii::app()->user->getState('key');
```

to

```
Yii::$app->user->XXXX('key', 'value');
Yii::$app->user->XXXX('key');
```

I know the `setState` method sets a value in the session (And db if the session is also in the db), but I can't figure out which of the new `\yii\web\User` method I should use as none of the `login`, `setIdentity`, `switchIdenty` methods seem to work the same way.

**More info if needed**: The "setState()" code is used to save the user id entered in a text field, which will then be used on the next page to ask the password.

Comment: is the above code used to add extra variables/fields for the logged in user via webuser component? you might need to add the file code relevant to the above problem which you were using in `yii1`

Comment: Thanks for the answer friend, will do :) However I think it's when a user is logging in, by first saving the user if, then on the next page ask a password.

Comment: Added an answer see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

This feature was dropped in Yii2. You should use `Yii::$app->session` in this cases, because `setState/getState` was just simple wrappers on it.

About prefix for `user` session

Simply use

```
Yii::$app->session->set('user.some_param',$someparam);
```

and use below to retrieve

```
Yii::$app->session->get('user.some_param' , $defaultValue);
```

Or you can implement this feature from Yii1 in your own class. For flashes see [**`CODE`**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/yii/web/Session.php#L581)

Comment: The old Yii1 User class seems to be pretty well embedded in the that app so I'm a bit concerned bypassing it and just using the session component might break things, but I'll try it and accept your solution if I see it works well in a few days! :)

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper sure take your time no problem